# vhdl error: integer literal cannot have negative exponent

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

The Quartus compiler reports the said error message at this line

```
constant LIMIT : float (5 downto -27) := 1E-12;
```

the constant is float type, why is it treated as an integer?

This constant is used only in if-statements and is compared to another float type variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal `1E-12` is an integer, since the mantissa (1 before 'E') is an integer; for a `real` type literal type write `1.0E-12`.

But that returns a VHDL `real` type, and not a `float` as used in the VHDL `float_generic_pkg` package.  For a `float` type constant use the `to_float` functions in the `float_generic_pkg` package.